# how to keep a ul open while other ul's toggle

Tags: jquery

I have a ul that I want to stay open while other ul's are able to toggle. When the page loads, the html looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/q9munmab/

```
<div class="leftNav">
   <ul>
       <li>
           <div class="active">Test</div>
           <ul class="navtoggle nonactive">
              <li><a></a></li>
              <li><a></a></li>
              <li><a class="current"></a></li>
           </ul>
           <div>Test 1</div>
           <ul class="navtoggle nonactive">
              <li><a></a></li>
              <li><a></a></li>
              <li><a></a></li>
           </ul>
           <div>Test 2</div>
           <ul class="navtoggle nonactive">
              <li><a></a></li>
              <li><a></a></li>
              <li><a></a></li>
           </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Class "active" varies depending on which of the 3 links you click on, while class "current" is the page you are actually on. I've tried multiple variations of toggles but can't seem to figure out how to keep which ever ( div class "active" along with the ul toggled solid ) while you can toggle between the other two. Then when you click on the li a, the page will load again and start over.

```
 $('.navContainer li div').click(function () {
   var $t = $(this);
   var $next = $t.next('.navtoggle');
   var $back = $('.current:visible').closest('ul').prev();
   $(this).not('.leftNav li div.active').toggleClass('nonactive');
   $('.navtoggle').not($back).slideToggle();
 });
```

Comment: please confirm, did you mean when clicked on the title div, the corresponding next UL should hide or display?

Comment: what is your requirement cannot figure out! so please add some more details upon your requirement.

Comment: Yes when you click on a div, the next ul should toggle, but the active ul should stay open until the li a is clicked which will load that page

Comment: hey @keith, check my answer below, check if it is right as per you required..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/q9munmab/3/

As per my info, this could work for you. the solution is simple with `not` selector. here is how you use it.

```
$(".navContainer ul>li>div:not(.active)").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

**UPDATED (to hide other UL's)**

working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/q9munmab/5/

additionally added `$(this).next().slideToggle().siblings("ul").hide();`

use of siblings to target other UL's, in order to hide.

**UPDATED (when you say, nothing happens to active UL when clicked on other divs)**

working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/q9munmab/7/

```
$(".navContainer ul>li>div.active").next().show().addClass("no-effect");
$(".navContainer ul>li>div:not(.active)").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle().siblings("ul:not(.no-effect)").hide();
});
```

added an extra class on load, which only effects to active div's UL, and again use of `not` selector to avoid activity on Active Div and UL.

Comment: i apologize, I didn't add in one css, that is that the ul's are display: none; to start, only the active div with the ul underneath is shown with the li a: current highlighted

Comment: I guess I didn't tell you this as well, but when a toggle opens and you click on the other to toggle, that one needs to close so only 1 other ul is open ( besides the loaded ul )

Comment: what happens for the active div? means this should be visible when loaded?

Comment: nothing happens to the active div, it stays active while the ul stays open, the other clickable div's with the display: none; ul's underneath are the only ones that change

Comment: @Keith check my updated answer, does this solves your requirement?

Comment: this works great on fiddle, still working on getting mine to work